# Java printing array with nested loop

Tags: java, arrays

I misunderstand something in this for loop. Can someone please clarify?

```
String[][] artikelTabelle;

    artikelTabelle = new String[2][2]; 

    artikelTabelle[0][0] = "Cow";
    artikelTabelle[0][1] = "Sheep";
    artikelTabelle[1][0] = "Dog";
    artikelTabelle[1][1] = "Lion";


    for(int i = 0; i < artikelTabelle.length; i++){ 
        for(int j = 0; j < artikelTabelle[0].length; j++){ 
            System.out.println(artikelTabelle[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

At first i and j are 0. Consequently, the array [0][0] (Cow) is printed. 
But during the second iteration, aren't i and j both 1, because of i++ and j++? Meaning that Lion should be printed? What do I misunderstand here? And since artikelTabelle[0].length has the length 2 - why would it be false to replace it with the number 2?

Comment: be vary that the inner loop ( the one with j ) is iterated twice, before `i` is incremented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two loops, one outer loop and another inner loop nested inside the outer loop.

This means that for each iteration of the outer loop (before each time `i` is incremented), the entire inner loop is executed (i.e. `j` goes from 0 to `artikelTabelle[0].length` before `i` is incremented).

Therefore first `artikelTabelle[0][0]` is printed, followed by `artikelTabelle[0][1]` (not by `artikelTabelle[1][1]`). `artikelTabelle[1][1]` is only printed in the second iteration of the outer loop.

As for whether to use `2` instead of `artikelTabelle[0].length`, the latter is safer, since you don't have to change a hard-coded `2` if later you change the dimensions of the array.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand now. But to be sure: At first the inner loop is executed, before it gets incremented. Then artikelTabelle[0][0] is printed. And then the inner loop is executed again with j incremented. j is one and artikelTabelle[0][1] gets printed. Then the inner for loop notices, that if it increments again (to 2) the condition that 2 < 2 won't work. Therefore it goes to the outer loop and increments i. i is now 1. It doesn't go through the inner for loop and prints artikelTabelle[1][0]. Then the inner for loop is executed again and artikelTabelle[1][1] is printed. Is that right?

Comment: @TeachMeSenpai Yes that's right, assuming you meant to write `It goes through` and not `It doesn't go through` in the next to last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

artikelTabelle[0].length is indeed 2.

However, you are misreading the loops. It goes like this:

You start off with i being 0, and j being 0. You print out artikelTabelle[0][0].
Now, we're still in the second for loop. Our condition for termination hasn't been met yet. So i is still 0, and we increment j to 1. Now we print out artikelTabelle[0][1]. Since our condition is now met to terminate the second for loop, we resume our first loop. i is incremented to 1, and we repeat the process. We print out artikelTabelle[1][0] and then artikelTabelle[1][1].

Hopefully I was able to help!

Answer (score 2):

The outer `for` loop will execute whatever is inside it for the amount of times you specified.

The inner code (which is also a `for` loop here) will thus be executed multiple times.

The variable `j` is scoped to, and initialized in the outer loop, meaning that when the outer loop starts for the second time, the previous variable no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

in you code `artikelTabelle[0].length = 2`  and  `artikelTabelle.length = 2`so for outer i loop increased by 1 than inner j for loop loopind two time like this :

i =0 =>j=0,j=1 ;
i =1 =>j=0,j=1 ;

```
for(int i = 0; i < artikelTabelle.length; i++){ 
        for(int j = 0; j < artikelTabelle[0].length; j++){ 
            System.out.println(artikelTabelle[i][j]);
        }
    }
```